# Azure AD B2C breaks OIDC spec

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, api-gateway, aad-b2c

I've configured a custom policy with AAD B2C IEF per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) link and am now trying to integrate it into API Gateway as a JWT authorizer per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html) link.

However, attempting to configure the authorizer throws an error

> error updating API Gateway v2 authorizer
> BadRequestException
> Caught exception when connecting to https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-id-here/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration for issuer https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-id-here/v2.0/.
> Please try again later.
> Error:
> Invalid issuer:
> https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-id-here/v2.0/.
> Issuer must have a valid discovery endpoint ended with '/.well-known/openid-configuration

The actual discovery endpoint is https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-domain.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration, however, that returns a doc as below, which has a different issuer than the discovery URL.

```json
{
  "issuer": "https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-id-here/v2.0/",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-domain.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-domain.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-domain.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/logout",
  "jwks_uri": "https://tenant-domain.b2clogin.com/tenant-domain.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/discovery/v2.0/keys",
  "response_modes_supported": [
    "query",
    "fragment",
    "form_post"
  ],
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token",
    "id_token",
    "id_token token",
    "token",
    "token id_token"
  ],
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "pairwise"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_post",
    "client_secret_basic"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "name",
    "given_name",
    "family_name",
    "email",
    "sub",
    "tid",
    "iss",
    "iat",
    "exp",
    "aud",
    "acr",
    "nonce",
    "auth_time"
  ]
}
```

Looking at [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/38427) issue and the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig), it looks like AAD is not spec compliant.

Is there any way to get this to work or do I have to move to a spec-compliant OIDC provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to configure  issuer URL ***including  tfp*** for token compatibility.

For more details see: [***Token compatibility***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#compatibility)
which  says:

> **Note** :  iss claim i.e; issuer identifies tenant of azure ad b2c that
> issued the token. Usually the value is some thing like  this
> :`https://<domain>/{B2C tenant GUID}/v2.0/`
>
> But I**f your application or library needs Azure AD B2C to be
> compliant with the [*OpenID Connect Discovery 1.0 spec*](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html), use this
> `https://<domain>/tfp/{B2C tenant GUID}/{Policy ID}/v2.0/`** as it
> includes IDs for both the Azure AD B2C tenant and the user flow that
> was used in the token request.

[image]

*For example:*

```
“issuer” : “https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/tfp/c5b2xxxxxxxxx0-8axxxxxx3d3b/B2C_1A_signin/v2.0/”
```

or

```
https://{tenantID}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenantID}/{policy-name}/v2.0/
```

**References:**

1. [Configure the Azure Active Directory B2C provider manually - Power
   Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/configure-azure-ad-b2c-provider-manual)
2. [AzureAD Authentication with AWS API Gateway v2 JWT Authorizers |
   rayterrill.com](https://www.rayterrill.com/2020/04/08/AzureADAPIGatewayv2JWTAuthorizer.html)

Comment: Reference 1 is the key, this is an opt in issuer format and must be configured on the flow

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @kavyasaraboju-MT, if you're using custom policies, you must set the `IssuanceClaimPattern` to `AuthorityWithTfp` in the `JwtIssuer` Tehcnical Profile per [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/jwt-issuer-technical-profile).

e.g. using the LocalAccounts pack in [active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/LocalAccounts), add the element `<Item Key="IssuanceClaimPattern">AuthorityWithTfp</Item>` to the `<Metadata>` [element](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L795)